# Can a boolean value concerning changing the sign or not of a scalar value considered a 1D rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

So going descending order on dimensions:

3D: 3 scaling scalars, 3 rotation scalars, 3 translation scalars

2D: 2 scaling scalars, 1 rotation scalars, 2 translation scalars

1D: 1 scaling scalar, **1 rotation boolean (?)**, 1 translation scalar

The reason I'm asking about 1D Rotation being a boolean is because one can make a point jump across a pivot(P), the origin or other value.
The second example in the image, with P on 1, has the conjugation: 
-1 -(P) = -2:  <=>  (-)-2 = 2  <=>  2 + (P) = 3

[image]

So could changing the sign considered a 1D rotation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of rotations can be described by the set of orthogonal matrices (i.e. matrices such that $A^T = A^{-1}$) with determinant $1$.

An orthogonal matrix with determinant $-1$ is an improper rotation or a reflection combined with a rotation

So, in the sense of this definition, you'd consider it a reflection, since the matrix would be $A=[-1]$ which has determinant $-1$.

Comment: I completely forgot about Reflection since for my 3D context reflecting a 3D mesh usually requires flipping the mesh normals.
And I guess given Reflection can be achieved with -1 Scale, I don't need to worry about it, given Scale is already there. Thanks!